# Django cmd color output with colorama

Tags: django, cmd, colors, output, colorama

[colorama](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama) allows colored text output in cmd for python. And it's working.

```
import colorama
colorama.init()
print('[31mThis outputs red text![39m')
```

And we can set color output for django runserver by setting environment var in cmd with `set DJANGO_COLORS=light`. I added `import colorama` and `colorama.init()` in the beginning of `manage.py`. But it's not working.

Is it possible to make Django dev server output colored logs to cmd using colorama?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `os.environ['ANSICON'] = 'on'` to your `manage.py` file.